# How to assign Partial Values in a C# object using Inline Assignment

Tags: c#, inline, observablecollection

I'm having a Collection of a Model

```
public class MobileModelInfo
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Catagory { get; set; }
    public string Year { get; set; }
}

Public Class MainClass
{
    public MainClass()
    {
        MobileModelInfo mobObject = new MobileModelInfo();
        mobObject.Name = "Apple iPhone 6";
        SetMobileDetails(mobObject);
    }

    private void SetMobileDetails(MobileModelInfo mobObject)
    {
        mobObject.Catagory = "Ultra Smart Phone";
        mobObject.Year = "2015";
    }
}
```

In the SetMobileDetails() Method set the partial values to the Object of MobileModelInfo. Here I need to assign the Values via Inline. How Can I achieve this

For Example: `new MobileModelInfo() { Catagory = "Ultra Smart Phone", Year = "2015" }`

Kindly assist me...

Note: One of the Property is set in Constructor and the remaining Properties is going to set in SetMobileDetails() Method.

Comment: You shouldn't be passing members (`mobObject`) to a class's own methods (`SetMobileDetails`) anyway, why do you do that? What _exactly_ are you asking for? What does _"I need to assign the Values via Inline"_ mean? Where do you want to use the code shown?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [named parameter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264739.aspx) but you need to pass the value for properties of object

```
private void SetMobileDetails(string catagory="", string year="")
{
    //...
}
```

You probably need to have a constructor that all three property values

```
public MainClass(string name, string catagory="", string year="")
{
    mobObject.Name = name;
    SetMobileDetails(catagory: "Ultra Smart Phone", year : "2015");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below code to solve your problem thank you.

```
void SetMobileDetails(String Catagory String Year )
{

    new MobileModelInfo() { Catagory = "Ultra Smart Phone", Year = "2015" }

}
```

Also Make overload of this for when property are change like below

```
 void SetMobileDetails(String Catagory)
    {

        new MobileModelInfo() { Catagory = "Ultra Smart Phone"}

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is all you need:

```
public class MobileModelInfo
{
  public string Name { get; private set; }
  public string Catagory { get; set; }
  public string Year { get; set; }

  public MobileModelInfo(string name)
  {
    Name = name;
  }
}
```

Usage:

```
var iphone = new MobileModelInfo("Apple iPhone") {Catagory = "Mobile", Year = "2016"};
```

Comment: Thanks for your contribution. But my requirement is how to write partial assignment within the Method SetMobileDetails() as I mentioned in the Source Code.

Comment: Ok. Then I can hardly imagine why do you need "inline assignment", because normally it's "inline initialization". 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397680.aspx 
But probably it's something from your requirements.